# How can I fix emails googlesheets

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets, format

Help. I'm trying to send an automated email using this code.

```
function checkIn() {
  var aemail=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
  var tracker= aemail.getSheetByName("Tracker");
  var template= aemail.getSheetByName("Templates");

  var message=template.getRange('B3').getValue();
  var signature= template.getRange('C3').getValue();

  for (var i=2; i<=2;i++) {    
    var sname =tracker.getRange('A'+i).getValue();
    var subject = tracker.getRange('B'+i).getValue();
    var eaddress = tracker.getRange('C'+i).getValue();
    var finalmsg = ""
    
    finalmsg="Hello"+""+sname+","+"\n"+"\n"+message+"\n"+signature;

    MailApp.sendEmail(eaddress,subject,finalmsg);
  }
}
```

The email sends but the text alignment is to the right and does not expand to the email space. How can I fix this? I fixed it once but can not remember how. I know it's not code-related.

[image]

Comment: the text alignment looks left to me - you fix it by removing line feeds from the message

Comment: I found another form that talks about gmailapp breaking emails into lines because of plain text. they advised using MailApp.send email(eaddress,subject,{htmlBody:finalmsg}); but when I do, it returns {object,object}

Comment: @BlessingsBestowed  Sorry, I was wrong with my answer before, I have added an edit to it to show you how you might use the htmlBody. If you are still having troubles don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it will depend on the data in the range `B3`. It probably has newlines included in it - if its not that then maybe its best to share a sample sheet so that it can be tested.

You can also try and add this code to replace newlines with spaces

Change

```js
 var message=template.getRange('B3').getValue();
```

To

```js
var message=template.getRange('B3').getValue().replaceAll("\n", " ")
```

If you want more control over how things look, you can also try using an HTML body with the [`sendEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) method. Using it like this:

```js
MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'example', 'body without html', {
    htmlBody:"<h1>Body with HTML</h1>"
});
```

The normal body is included since not all clients render HTML, so if a particular mail client does not render HTML, then it will use the plain text version.

That said, I do think that your issue is to do with newline characters `\n` making their way into your message.

#### Reference

- [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)
- [`sendEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

## EDIT

I was wrong.

After running some tests it is true that if your Email is completely plain text, then Gmail will automatically insert line breaks.

You will need to use the `options` and `htmlBody` parameters mentioned above.

You can use it like this:

```js
function sampleEmail() {
  
  var message="Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks Long Text without line breaks "


  MailApp.sendEmail("[YOUR EMAIL]","test", message,{htmlBody:"<p>"+ message +"</p>"});
}
```

The arguments are as follows:

- The email of the recipient
- the subject
- the plain text message (as a fall back in case the client's email does not support HTML)
- the `options` parameter with one attribute `htmlBody` where the message is simply wrapped with `<p>` HTML tags.

This text will now adapt and fill the width of the screen in an email client that supports HTML, like Gmail.